# No column named in sqlite java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have seen many times that I can't find the solution of `no column named`. Can anyone please help me? 
Thank you very much in advance :)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LUGGAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" +
                                        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + 
                                        KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + 
                                        KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LUGGAGE_TABLE);
}



public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LuggageDataCenter";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "luggage";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
    private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LUGGAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LUGGAGE_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Luggage luggage) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, luggage.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_CODE, luggage.getCode()); // Contact Phone
       // values.put(KEY_NUMBER, luggage.getNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Luggage> getAllContacts() {
        List<Luggage> contactList = new ArrayList<Luggage>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Luggage luggage = new Luggage();
                luggage.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            //    luggage.setCode(cursor.getString(1));
          //      luggage.setNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(luggage);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace

```
01-07 18:45:43.070: I/Adreno200-EGL(16078): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
01-07 18:45:51.950: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16078): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078): Error inserting code=100000HKG name=Lee Chung Ming 
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: luggage.number may not be NULL (code 19)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:787)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at com.airportapplication.app.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:64)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at com.airportapplication.app.LuggageVer.onActivityResult(LuggageVer.java:87)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5197)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3160)
01-07 18:45:53.600: E/SQLiteDatabase(16078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3207)
```

I have already reinstalled the app, but still not work.

Comment: What is the *final* SQL string used? What is *wrong* with it? If not sure, try running the *final* SQL string for the CREATE TABLE from an interactive sqlite session and break it down until the problem is found (hint: look near the end).

Comment: You have a comma at the end that shouldn't be there (before closing bracket).

Comment: 01-07 18:03:46.892: E/SQLiteLog(14244): (1) table luggage has no column named code
01-07 18:03:46.912: E/SQLiteDatabase(14244): Error inserting code=100000HKG name=Lee Chung Ming 
01-07 18:03:46.912: E/SQLiteDatabase(14244): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table luggage has no column named code (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO luggage(code,name) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: There is the final string

Comment: private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
    private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app so that `onCreate()` is called again.

Comment: // values.put(KEY_NUMBER, luggage.getNumber()); // Contact Phone
uncomment this line becz require column you are inserting record
  values.put(KEY_NUMBER, ""); // Contact Phone

Comment: Thank you so much. I really feel I am so stupid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`you added extra , & + at the end` so please format it properly like below:

```
String CREATE_LUGGAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Comment: Don't make it difficult to find "the change". State it explicitly.

Comment: 01-07 18:03:46.892: E/SQLiteLog(14244): (1) table luggage has no column named code
01-07 18:03:46.912: E/SQLiteDatabase(14244): Error inserting code=100000HKG name=Lee Chung Ming 
01-07 18:03:46.912: E/SQLiteDatabase(14244): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table luggage has no column named code (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO luggage(code,name) VALUES (?,?)


There is the error message.

Comment: And the final string are

Comment: private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
    private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

Comment: change database name or uninstall app from your device then run it. then post your DB code & logcat also.

Comment: while compiling: INSERT INTO luggage(code,name) VALUES (?,?) you are inserting two column so arising this type of error
i.e INSERT INTO luggage
VALUES ('test','test','test');